# Creating Local User on Remote Windows Server and Add to Administrator Group

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting, get-wmiobject

I have Created PowerShell script to create User on remote Windows Server and add to Administrator group:

```
$Computer = Read-Host "Computer name:"
$UserName = Read-Host "User name:"
$Password = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrator,group"
$User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$UserName,user"
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText –Force)
$User.SetPassword($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
```

And It gives me below error:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetPassword":                "
The user name could not be found.
At C:\test1.ps1:7 char:18
+ $User.SetPassword <<<< ($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],  ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

The following exception occurred while retrieving member "Add": "The specified
local group does not exist.
At C:\test1.ps1:8 char:16
+ $AdminGroup.Add <<<< ($User.Path)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [],  ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a user you need to actually create a user. The statement you're using returns a user account only if it already exists:

> ```
> $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$UserName,user"
> ```

Probably the simplest way to create a local account is the [`net`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865.aspx) command:

```
& net user $UserName ($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password) /expires:never /add
```

Using the [`WinNT` provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772237.aspx) is possible, but more complicated:

```
$acct = [adsi]"WinNT://$Computer"
$user = $acct.Create('User', $UserName)
$user.SetPassword($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$user.SetInfo()
```

Also, as others have already pointed out, you misspelled the name of the administrators group (that's what's causing the second error). Since the name of that group could be localized, depending on what language version you're running, you may want to resolve it anyway:

```
$AdminGroupName = Get-WmiObject Win32_Group -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND SID='S-1-5-32-544'" |
                  Select-Object -Expand Name
$AdminGroup = [adsi]"WinNT://$Computer/$AdminGroupName,group"
```

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - Thanks a lot User add on Remote works, however it doesn't getting add into Administrators group despite of above setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an "s" in "administrators" below.

```
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrator,group"
```

I have a (working) script that adds a user to the local administrators group and that line looks like this:

```
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually never created user. Also you want to correct Administrators group name. I have fixed your code:

```
$Computer = Read-Host "Computer name:"
$UserName = Read-Host "User name:"
$Password = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators,group"
$CompObject = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer"
$User = $CompObject.Create('User',$UserName)
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText –Force)
$User.SetPassword($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$User.SetInfo()
$AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
```