# Creating Local Users and Add to Administrator Group on Remote Windows Servers

Tags: powershell

I am still a newbie in using powershell and I really see how useful it is in completing some of my sysadmin tasks.
I have Servers from DMZ and remote sites (unjoined).
Trying to figure out how to create local accounts (getting list from csv or txt file) and add them to local admin group from a list of servers. I have a found a PS script from the post below (thanks to Kirill Pashkov) which is exactly what I am looking for but just wondering if its possible to get the list of users and servers from a file like csv or txt.

Should it be like this?
$Computer = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt" instead of read-host?

## original script

```
$Computer = Read-Host "Computer name:"
$UserName = Read-Host "User name:"
$Password = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators,group"
$CompObject = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer"
$User = $CompObject.Create('User',$UserName)
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -
ArgumentList $UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText –
Force)
$User.SetPassword($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$User.SetInfo()
$AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
```

[answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276857/creating-local-user-on-remote-windows-server-and-add-to-administrator-group/48638684#48638684)